# How can i make a comparison between two c_strings checking also if a char has already been compared?

Tags: c, arrays, char

In specific, i'm actually coding a function taken from "Scrabble" game. I have to get the a word of 10 chars and, given the player's letters, check if that word can be made with those letters or not. I'm getting problems in checking words that have more letters of the same type. Here's my code : `

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int num = 10;
    char lett[num] = {'f','c','a','a','b','s','t','o','e','m'};
    char word[10];
    bool isUsable[num] = {true};

    // Input word

    do {
        printf("Insert the word : ");
        scanf(" %s", &word[0]); 
        system("CLS");
    } while (strlen(word)>num);

    printf("your word is : %s \n", word);

    // Verificy word

    bool isChecked;

    for (int i = 0;i<strlen(word);i++) {
        isChecked = false;

        // compare every char of word[] with array lett[]

        for(int j = 0;j<num;j++) {


            // if word[i] = lett[j] --> make boolean associated to that letter not usable anymore and make the the boolean associated to the char of the word checked

            if (word[i]==lett[j]) {

                if (isUsable[j]) {
                    isUsable[j] = false;
                    isChecked = true;
                }

            }

        }

        // if at least one char of the word result not checked display error

        if (!isChecked) {

            printf("\n You have not the necessary letters!\n");
            system("pause");
            return 0;

        }                                   
    }       

   // rest of the code ..

return 0;
}
```

for example, the code works for the word ("cab"), but won't work for the word ("acab"). (sorry for lessical game :D)

I was thinking i may be wrong using a boolean array but i can't figure out how not to use it.

I also thought there may be a solution with the use of a pointer, but i'm still not that good in managing solutions with pointers..

The last thought was of a stupid mistake, but i couldn't find it..
so.. anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: That more looks like pure C code to me, I can't spot anything C++ specific. Also to find _stupid errors_ fire up your program in the debugger and inspect stepping through line by line. Stack Overflow isn't a online debugging service.

Comment: @Ghislo, if the title is as you suggested, `C++`, then there is very little to any C++ specific things in your code.  If it is `C++`, then there are `C++` specific solutions that do not require writing loops to find if one sequence is contained in another sequence.  In addition to that, if it is `C++`, why not use `cin`, and `std::string`?  If I'm wrong and it is actually a `C` program, change your title to reflect this.

Comment: Actually i'm following a c++ course in my university, but these are the tools that I've learned till now. So the exercise requires me to be able to go for it with the tools I've learned till now . I hope this isn't against the community rules!

Comment: So if you want 'plain C', rather than C++, please [edit] your question and remove it from your title. Note that even mentioning it in the title is not necessary - that's what tags are for. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way! Based in the edits that others did for you, you may want to read [how to properly format your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont break from this loop:

```
 for(int j = 0;j<num;j++) {
        if (word[i]==lett[j]) {
            if (isUsable[j]) {
                isUsable[j] = false;
                isChecked = true;
```

This means that every 'a' in the list will be marked with `isUsable = false` when you check the first letter of `acab`. You need to have a `break` when you find the first letter:

```
if (isUsable[j]) {
    isUsable[j] = false;
    isChecked = true;
    break;
```

The second problem is that you are not initializing your `isUsable` array correctly.

[Here is a live example of it working.](http://ideone.com/zUzC61)

Comment: Thank you mate! I totally forgot about the break statement!!!
Even thought i thought my bool[] initialization was right.. so i learned something!! I initialized it with a for loop!

Answer (score 2):

Undefined behavior

`strlen(word)>num` imposes no control about the maximum number of characters to read.  Once too many are are read - anything goes.  Its undefined behavior.

```
int num = 10;
char word[10];
do {
    printf("Insert the word : ");
    scanf(" %s", &word[0]); 
} while (strlen(word)>num);
```

Instead:

```
int num = 10;
char word[10];
printf("Insert the word : ");
scanf("%9s", word);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!